# How to display a NumPy complex array in the variables inspector

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I am using the Jupyter notebook in VSCode here; I define a NumPy array, where is complex numbers in the array, and I want to display it in the Jupyter variables to see the details in it. but I encounter this problem, all the cells show like this, does anyone know how to display it? thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a short slab of Jupyter Notebook in VSCode for now. Other people have mentioned this on GitHub:

[Dataviewer enrichment for List, Dictionary and Row](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/2221)

[Data Viewer/Variable Explorer support for non-array like objects](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1138)

You can upvote the feature request and join the discussion.